# Vue Async Stack Trace Error on Fresh Spark Install + Homestead

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

I have a fresh installation of Laravel Spark running on a per-project Homestead instance.  When I go to the settings section on a demo user I've created, I get this error in the JS console:

`Uncaught Error: [vue] async stack trace`

All of the pages in the settings section load and seem to be correct (Profile, Security, Invoices, etc) except for Subscription.  The content section of the page is blank.  The nav and side menu are still there but there's nothing else on the page.

Any help with fixing this error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to run `gulp` from the command line.